# Mysql root password error

Tags: apache2, password, mysql, php

My php -v is

```
php -v
PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

i try to install php apache to my ubuntu and it asks me to enter root password. But i cant find the password. I follow this guide

http://tecadmin.net/install-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04/#

Step 3 – Install MySQL
i do those

```
sudo apt install mysql-server php-mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php-mysql is already the newest version (1:7.0+35ubuntu6).
mysql-server is already the newest version (5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-28 linux-headers-4.4.0-28-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-28-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-31-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 54 not upgraded
```

and then this

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root: 
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Probably i had php or mysql before.

I cant reach that file. I used ubuntu root passsword root is not that root.

```
 gedit /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

also doesnot show password.

Comment: Yeah your system's root password is not the same. Have you tried resetting your MySQL password?

Comment: yes http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291319/how-to-change-mysql-root-password-using-mysql-v5-7 i tried this. probably it couldnot changebecayse it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Step-by-step:

1. Stop MySQL Service:

   sudo service mysql stop
2. Kill all running mysqld:

   sudo killall -9 mysqld
3. Starting mysqld in Safe mode:

   sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
4. Start mysql client:

   mysql -u root
5. After successful login, please execute this command to change any password:

   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
6. You can update mysql root password:

   UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpwd') WHERE User='root';

...this did not work for me so i did:

```
In MySQL 5.7, the password field in mysql.user table field was removed, now the field name is authentication_string.

First choose the database:
mysql> use mysql; And then show the tables:
mysql> show tables; You will find the user table, and see its fields:  
mysql> describe user; You will realize there is no field named password, the password field is named authentication_string. So, just do this:
update user set authentication_string=password('XXXX') where user='root'; As suggested by @Rui F Ribeiro, alternatively you can run:
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root' = PASSWORD('new_password');
```

7. Please execute this command:

   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
8. Exit mysql console:

   exit
9. Kill mysqld_safe and start mysql:

   sudo killall mysqld_safe && sudo service mysql start